# Python deployment on webserver with CGI

Tags: python, flask, cgi, wsgi

I have a python script that I want to make accessible through a website with an userinterface.

I was experimenting with Flask, but I'm not sure this is the right tool for what I want to do.

My script takes userdata (.doc/.txt files), does something with it and returns it to the user. I don't want to save anything and I don't think that I need a database for this (is this right?). The file will be temporarily saved on the server and everything will be deleted once the user downloaded the modified file.

My webhosting provider supports Python and only accepts CGI. I read that WSGI is the preferred method to use with Python and that CGI has scaling issues and can only process one request at a time. I'm not sure if I understand this correctly. If several users would upload files at the same time, the server would only accept one request or overwrite previous requests? Or it can do one request per unique IP address/user?

Would CGI be ok for the simple get/process/return task of my python script or should I look into a hosting service that uses WSGI?

I had a look at Heroku and Render to deploy a flask app, but I think I could do that through my webhosting provider I guess.

Comment: We can't say anything without knowing the load requirements (number of concurrent users and jobs are the main ones). Why don't you simply deploy and see if it performs acceptably well? It's not hard to re-deploy it using WSGI/ASGI on another host if it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Since the site is not online I don't know the numbers. Hopefully many! Lets say 10 users per minute.

I'll try using CGI! I wasn't aware that I can re-deploy somewhere else. I thought I need to consider WSGI when making the flask app and setting up my environment.

Comment: That's pretty much close to zero load unless the documents they upload are huge. Use whatever method is easier/cheaper for you.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in this topic,

I decided to deploy my app on render.com, which supports gunicorn (WSGI).